# Haskell - Let in expression

Tags: haskell

Im trying to replicate the example of the book "Learn a Haskell for a Great Good", with the use of `let` and `in`.

The thing is that, although I write the same code in the same way, it doesn't work and shows me a failure with the second "=" in the second variable.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

```
cylinder :: (RealFloat a) => a ->a ->a
cylinder r h = 
      let sideArea = 2*pi*r*h
          topArea = pi*r^2
      in sideArea + 2*topArea
```

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: When running this through `ghci`, this works for me...

Comment: This smells like an indentation issue. Are you using tabs? Run GHC with `-fwarn-tabs` and if it barks at you, replace the tabs with spaces.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
   Prelude CA> let cylinder r h = 
   Prelude CA|       let sideArea = 2*pi*r*h
   Prelude CA|           topArea = pi*r^2
   Prelude CA|       in sideArea + 2*topArea
   Prelude CA| 
   Prelude CA> cylinder 5 9
   439.822971502571
```

I guess it's simply an indentation problem

```
   <interactive>:48:5: parse error (possibly incorrect indentation)
```